# Finding a function using first derivative

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I have some data about just first derivative of a function. Also, I know a point of this function(e.g. (x1,y1)). How can I obtain the function? All my date are numerical.

dev f(x)=[ 580.00 , 479.7308 , 367.5010 , 289.7887 , 243.7456 , 212.5099 , 194.4842 , 180.0328 , 172.0009 , 164.2524 , 156.5040 , 153.0849 , 150.6759 , 147.1401 , 143.6043 , 139.9884 , 136.3724]

for x=[ 0.0 , 6.2500 ,  12.5000  , 18.7500  , 25.0000  , 31.2500  , 37.5000 , 43.7500 ,  50.0000 ,  56.2500  , 62.5000 ,  68.7500 ,  75.0000 ,  81.2500 ,  87.5000 , 93.7500 , 100.0000]

(x1,y1)=(0 , 0)

Comment: Can you give us the data?

Comment: You can use Lagrange Interpolation to find f'(x) and then integrate it to find f(x)

Comment: Thanks all. I fitted it in MatLab using 'smoothingspline' and then integrated it using f(x)=integrate(cfit,x,x0). It works well.